# Efficient way to lookup values in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking up the prices of products based on `id_number` in another DataFrame called `df` and adding the prices of each product in my `df_pair` DataFrame. I am doing this right now in the following way:

```
df_pair['price_p1'] = df_pair['p1'].progress_apply(lambda x: df[df['id_number'] == x]['price'].iloc[0])
```

But it seems, it's too slow. Is there any other better solution to solve this?
My two DataFrame sample:
`df`:

| id_number | price | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B0000D9MYM | 12.5 |  |
| B0000D9MYL | 25.26 |  |
| B00ADHIGBA | 8.9 |  |
| B00H9OX598 | 10.56 |  |
| ... | .... |  |

`df_pair` looks like below:

| p1 | ... |
| --- | --- |
| B002HQCWYM |  |
| B00H9OX598 |  |
| B0000D9MYL |  |
| ... |  |

Note: the indices or the order of the `id_numbers` and `p1` values are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to `set_index` with "id_number" and `map` the `price`:

```
df_pair['price'] = df_pair['p1'].map(df1.set_index('id_number')['price'])
```

Output:

```
           p1  ...  price
0  B002HQCWYM  ...    NaN
1  B00H9OX598  ...  10.56
2  B0000D9MYL  ...  25.26
3         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_pair.merge(df.rename(columns={"id_number":"p1"}), how="left")
```

you can merge 2 dataframes by **merge func** but need same column name.
(or use left_on & right_on)

my eng is not good. so hard to exlain long.
if you have more question. tell me.

if **df** has many columns, slice **df** and use **df[["id_number", "price"]]** instead of **df**

and how can i make grey block on df? i don want make bold anymore

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id_number` is the index of `df` you can do something like:

```
df_pair.join(df, on='p1')['price'].sum()
```

A join is a standard database operation that basically merges two data frames by linking a column of one to the index of other.